# Visual Studio 2015 Include Directories vs Source Directories

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to understand when to use Include Directories and Source Directories. I have the source code to a class I'd like to use and want to point to it. Both the source and header files are in the same folder.

Should I put the location in both include directories and source directories? Most examples I have seen only use the Include Directories. Is the Include Directory meant for only headers and the Source for cpp files? Or another use case?

The other confusing part is the Additional Include Directories under C/C++ General. Is this preferred over the VC++ Directories or vice versa. Is this to be used for both .h and .cpp files?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  The folders in the project browser need not relate to directories on your disk.  They are populated by "filters", the default filter has separate source and include  The "Additional Include Directories" refers to file-system directories, not project browser folders, and is used to list all the directories the pre-processor will scan to find files referenced by `#include`.  Beyond that your question is a matter of opinion.

Comment: ***Is this to be used for both .h and .cpp files?*** Not `.cpp` files since you never include those.

Comment: ***Additional Include Directories under C/C++ General. Is this preferred over the VC++ Directories*** I prefer `Additional Include Directories` over using  `VC++ Directories` because I usually don't want all my projects to inherit the same include folders.

Comment: You need to add the source files (and probably headers as well) to your project. If they are in a different folder than your project you also need to add an entry for the Include Directory in either of the settings you mention.